# Rear wheel needed

Tags: road-bike, wheels

Rear wheel needed for women's 2014 Scattante road bike with the following details:
Front wheel- Alex Rims A Class AKX R3.0 700C Road Wheel 28 Alloy Black, stainless 14 gauge spokes. 
Cassette- Shimano Tiagra 12/28
Crankset- FSA Omega Compact 50/34
Tires- Hutchinson Nitro 700X23, 33TPI (I can reuse the rear tire.)
My matching rear wheel was destroyed when hit by a car. I will not ride this bike on the road again, but would like to use it in-house on a fluid trainer. Can anyone advise me where to purchase a matching wheel or an inexpensive, compatible rear wheel? Thank you.

Comment: Trainers are hard on a bike -- Depending on the type of damage the bike has incurred, I'm not sure I'd put it in a trainer.

Comment: @Batman can you please explain more?

Comment: You're clamping a bike in an area that experiences a lot of stress. When you ride the bike freely, you're flexing it freely, rather than fixing it. So, you can exacerbate some issues with a frame by putting one in a trainer, especially if its been damaged. You can search for frame failure in trainers and see a decent number of examples.

Comment: This question keeps being raised by the `bot.  Could you please post your comment as an answer, and click the "accept this answer" tick/check ?   Please also add any relevant experiences in the 6 months since you bought the new wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Look for road wheels with Shimano-compatible freehub. For trainer use, any wheel will do. With high end wheels you might find a tubular rim or Campagnolo freehub, but any low end wheel will work.

Comment: Thank you, ojs, for the advice. I purchased a Forte Titan at Performance Bike for a 40% price reduction. Looking forward to using it on my new Kinetic Road Machine.